Navigation bar button becomes smaller when using it as a UIViewRepresentable
I created a reusable share button view in SwiftUI that I added to a navigation view. Here is what that button looks like at a high level.
struct ShareButton: View {
    let url: URL?

    var body: some View {
        shareButton
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    private var shareButton: some View {
        if let url {
            Button {
                navigationRouter.presentActivityViewController(activityItems: [url],
                                                               applicationActivities: [])
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: Constants.Image.shareIcon)
            }
        }
    }

I centralize my navigation within a navigation router which is based on UIKit and due to some limitations highlighted in this question I had to move the whole share button implementation to a UIViewRepresentable.
That looks like this:
private struct ShareButtonRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    let url: URL
    let imageSystemName: String
    let tintColor: UIColor
    let navigationRouter: NavigationRouter?
    let action: (() -> Void)?
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton()
        let image = UIImage(systemName: imageSystemName)
        button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        button.tintColor = tintColor
        
        let uiAction = UIAction() { _ in
            navigationRouter?.presentActivityViewController(activityItems: [url],
                                                            applicationActivities: [],
                                                            source: button)
            action?()
        }
        
        button.addAction(uiAction, for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIButton, context: Context) { }
}

struct ShareButton: View {
    let url: URL?

    var body: some View {
        shareButton
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    private var shareButton: some View {
        if let url {
            ShareButtonRepresentable(url: url,
                                     imageSystemName: Constants.Image.shareIcon,
                                     tintColor: Constants.TintColor,
                                     navigationRouter: navigationRouter) {
                
            }
        }
    }


While everything seems to work, the button looks visibly smaller with this new implementation.
Before:

After:

How can I get the size to be like before using my new approach ?

Since the purpose of ShareButtonRepresentable is just to give the popup a source view, you don't actually need it to be the button itself. Write the button in SwiftUI as usual, and overlay it over a a UIViewRepresentable that is transparent. The hard part would be, how would the button tell the UIViewRepresentable to present the popup. (I don't have an answer yet, just throwing out ideas)

navigation is designed to be decentralised, i.e. with multiple .navigationDestination in many Views.

In your ShareButtonRepresentable code, create a large image config:
    let largeConfig = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(scale: .large) // Add this line
    let largeImage = image?.applyingSymbolConfiguration(largeConfig) // And this line
    button.setImage(largeImage, for: .normal)

And you will see its size should match SwiftUI's approach.
(SwiftUI has the .imageScale(.large) modifier applied to it. This modifier increases the size of the image.)

